# Sketch parametric curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

An exercise in my textbook asks to sketch the parametrical curve of the following equation:
$$x=e^t\cdot\cos(t)\\y=e^t\cdot\sin(t)\\t\ge0$$
I would usually try to solve one of the equations for t and replace on the other one, or even solve for $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ and do something like $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$, but both of them wouldn't work...
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why don't just choose values for t, calculate x and y and start plotting?

Comment: That could probably work... But I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to solve it.

Comment: Notice that this is part of the graph of the logarithmic spiral $r=e^{\theta}$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x^2 + y^2 = e^{2t}$. So your "radius" is increasing with time, and does not depend on the angle. The curve is a spiral. Choosing a few values of $t$ is good to try to get the picture. See the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28e%5Et+cos+t%2C+e%5Et+sin+t%29), down at "parametric plot".

Comment: Good! One last thing... How can I figure out the direction of motion of this curve? Is choosing some values of $t$ the best way to do that?

Comment: If $\alpha(t) = (e^t \cos t, e^t \sin t)$, then: $$\alpha'(t) = (-e^t\sin t + e^t\cos t, e^t\cos t + e^t \sin t) = \left(\sqrt{2} e^t \cos\left(t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right), \sqrt{2}e^t \sin\left(t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$
The tangent (velocity) vector gives the direction of motion. Try to plot a few tangent vectors to the curve.